# Trying to read value at xpath

Tags: html, xml, perl, xpath

I'm trying to get the value of the School District listed on this website: http://gis.nyc.gov/dcp/at/f1.jsp?submit=true&house_nbr=310&street_name=Lenox+Avenue&boro=1

I used Firebug to get the XPath of that value:
/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]

And would like to read it in with Perl. I wrote the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
use Data::Dumper;

my $tree= HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;

$tree->parse_file("test.html");

my @nb=$tree->findvalue( '/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]');

print Dumper(@nb);
```

But it just returns `$VAR1 = '';`.

Any suggestions. To get this to run, I just copied the source from the webpage into test.html.

Thank you!

Comment: Which browser are you using? To test, I see you used firefox to get the xpath?  Internet Explorer interprets XPath's differently (atleast it used to) FF td[2] = IE td[1]. M$ decided to start at index 0.

Comment: @Cromat I used Firefox, but would that make a difference? Doesn't it matter what HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath uses and not the browser I used to get the HTML?

Comment: Can't answer as I do not use PERL, but I can tell you that the HTML is not valid XML and there is nothing denoting that this is XHTML.

Comment: @Ted Johnson, Noone said it was XML or XHTML, so I don't get your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start tag of certain HTML elements (HTML, HEAD, BODY and TBODY) is optional. Take a look at

```
...<table><tr><td>Foo</td></tr></table>...
```

According to HTML, there are *four* elements represented by that snippet:

```
TABLE
   TBODY
      TR
         TD
```

Firefox creates all four elements, so it gives the following xpath for the TD element:

```
.../table/tbody/tr/td
```

HTML::TreeBuilder probably doesn't create elements when their start tags have been omitted, so it only creates *three* elements for that snippet:

```
TABLE
   TR
      TD
```

You'd need to use the following xpath to locate the TD element:

```
.../table/tr/td
```

I bet you'll find results if you removed the `tbody` tests from your xpath, as the TBODY elements are most likely not found in the file.

Comment: TBODY is valid XML and the tr is nested in the TBODY XML element.

Comment: @ikegami Any recommendations for reading the file in directly from the URL instead of having to save it to file?

Comment: @Jeff Erickson, `->new_from_content`

Comment: @Jeff Erickson, If you use `->parse`, don't forget to call `->eof`.

Comment: @Ted Johnson, What are you talking about? 1. We're talking about HTML, not XML. 2. I didn't say anything was invalid.